# How can I make div objects side by side with a container with a boarder?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I would like to make div objects side by side, and some ontop of one another.
here is my current code:

```css
    .active_deal{
        font-size: 18px;
        border: 2px solid;
        /*padding: 5px;*/
        /*padding-top: 5px;*/
        /*padding-bottom: 5px;*/
        border-radius: 4px;
        
    }
    .Deal_div_area{
        border-right: 3px dashed;
       max-width: 20%;
       max-height: 80%;
           padding: 10px;
       padding-top: 10px;
       padding-bottom: 10px;
       position:relative;
   
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="active_deal">

                <div class="Deal_div_area">
                <img src="https://i1.wp.com/theverybesttop10.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Top-10-Crazy-and-Unusual-Square-Foods-10-510x498.jpg?resize=100%2C586">
        </div>
    </div>
```

as you can see, the left section has an image, and I would like to make the right section have 2 text fields all ontop of one another for information on the image. I have tried putting div classes right next to it on my HTML file, however, this just places the text underneath my image rather than to the right of it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Google "css grids", "flexbox grid", "css layout templates" - should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this simple code:

```
  <div class="active_deal">

                <div class="Deal_div_area">
                <img src="https://i1.wp.com/theverybesttop10.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Top-10-Crazy-and-Unusual-Square-Foods-10-510x498.jpg?resize=100%2C586">
        </div>
    <div class="text-area">
      <h2> Title here</h2>
      <p> Some text here </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is the css:

```
 .active_deal{
        font-size: 18px;
        border: 2px solid;
        /*padding: 5px;*/
        /*padding-top: 5px;*/
        /*padding-bottom: 5px;*/
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        // justify-content: space-between;
        
    }
    .Deal_div_area{
        border-right: 3px dashed;
       max-width: 20%;
       max-height: 80%;
           padding: 10px;
       padding-top: 10px;
       padding-bottom: 10px;
       position:relative;
   
    }
.text-area{
  // your code for the text here
}
```